# how to remove recursive rules in r package "arulesSequence"

Tags: r, arules

I use arulesSequence package and ruleInduction function to generate sequence rules and the result contains recursive rules like:

```
{A} => {A}
{A, B} => {A, B}
```

how to get rid of these rules?

Answer (score 0):

Subset your rules afterwards:

```
library(arulesSequences)
example(cspade)
rules <- ruleInduction(s5, confidence = 0.0)
df <- data.frame(lhs = labels(lhs(rules)), rhs = labels(rhs(rules)), rules@quality, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
subset(df, lhs==rhs)
#          lhs     rhs support confidence      lift
# 22     <{F}>   <{F}>    0.25  0.2500000 0.2500000
# 1628 <{A,F}> <{A,F}>    0.25  0.3333333 0.4444444
# 2564   <{C}>   <{C}>    0.25  1.0000000 4.0000000
# 2981   <{B}>   <{B}>    0.25  0.2500000 0.2500000
# 3015 <{A,B}> <{A,B}>    0.25  0.3333333 0.4444444
# 3040   <{A}>   <{A}>    0.25  0.2500000 0.2500000

subset(df, lhs!=rhs)
# ...
```